# How to unsubscribe from observable without using ngOnDestroy or async pipe?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, subject

On clicking on any player name , the subject gets updated , the service returns an Observable and I'm displaying it in the component .

I'm trying to unsubscribe from the observable in my component before making a new subscription . Is there a way I can do that without using ngOnDestroy / async pipe?

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.playersubscription = this.playerService
      .getSelectedPlayer()
      .subscribe((player) => {
        this.selectedPlayer = player;
        // this.playersubscription.unsubscribe(); If I unsubscribe it here , the functionality breaks
      });
  }
```

Service:

```
 private selectedPlayer = new Subject<string>();

  getSelectedPlayer() {
    return this.selectedPlayer.asObservable();
  }

  updateSelectedPlayer(playerName: string) {
    this.selectedPlayer.next(playerName);
  }
```

This is what I have tried [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-noxyh7?file=src/app/app.component.ts) . Please help , thanks in advance!

Comment: if your actual service is obtaining the player via `HttpClient` and you return that observable in your service, it will auto unsubscribe after the call is complete so you don't need to do anything.

Comment: While switching between the selected players, I want to unsubscribe. Is there a way to do so? Component will never die in my case so I cannot use ngOnDestroy()

Comment: You need not to unsubscribe in your case (only in ngOnDestroy) ngOnInit will only calls one time when the component will be created. And ngOnDestroy only when the component will removed.

Comment: Why won't the component ever be destroyed?

Comment: In your case the app component is the only component that ever showing. Will your code be inside a child component (and liked with a router as example) then ngOnDestroy will be called if you navigate away from the component.

Comment: I currently don't understand why you want to unsubscribe before the component is destroyed. _"unsubscribe from the observable in my component before making a new subscription"_ - if your component doesn't get destroyed and recreated you don't create any new subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

So here i created a child component (named hello). Inside the child you will find your code. The app component has a button which will show/hide the child. So you see the console.logs of **ngOnInit** and **ngOnDestroy**.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yl2vg2?file=src/app/hello.component.ts) is the updated Stackblitz link.

***Hello Component (Child)***

```
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  selectedPlayer: string;
  playersubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private playerService: PlayerService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit');
    this.playersubscription = this.playerService
      .getSelectedPlayer()
      .subscribe((player) => {
        this.selectedPlayer = player;
        // this.playersubscription.unsubscribe(); If I unsubscribe it here , the functionality breaks
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.playersubscription.unsubscribe();
    console.log('ngOnDestroy');
  }

  players = [
    {
      name: 'Sachin',
      team: 'MI',
    },
    {
      name: 'Dhoni',
      team: 'CSK',
    },
    {
      name: 'Kohli',
      team: 'RCB',
    },
  ];

  selectPlayer(playerName) {
    this.playerService.updateSelectedPlayer(playerName);
  }
}
```

***App Component***

```
export class AppComponent {
  showChild: boolean = true;

  constructor() {}
  onShowHideClick() {
    this.showChild = !this.showChild;
  }
}


..... and HTML part

<h1>APP COMPONENT</h1>
<button (click)="onShowHideClick()">SHOW / HIDE children</button>
<hr />
<hello *ngIf="showChild"></hello>
```

Does it what you want and if you understand all you can select my post as answer. Thx!

Greetings, Florian